# How to hide/remove user profile icon in ms edge address bar?

Tags: browser, icons, microsoft-edge, profile

How to hide/remove user profile icon in ms edge address bar?

I know which account I use and expose profile image is not good for share screen for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

May be change profile picture may solve the security problem for now

Click on the profile -> manage profile setting -> edit -> change profile image

[image]

Press update and put dummy profile image
[image]

I hope there are a better way than change profile image